# Email verification

Tags: php, mysql, email, newsletter

I'm creating a newsletter subscription app. I want to implement email verification to prevent spam/bot signups (well, at least so I can delete them afterwards). I've been struggling with confirmation key but though of a simpler solution:

1. User clicks submit -> is inputed into database (verified = 0)
2. User receives generic email ("Click me to verify") -> Verified page (verified = 1)

Would this work? Are there any potential issues which might come up?

Comment: Looks good to me.. and there are always issues when sending email to unknown addresses.. just ignore the bounces

Comment: Sure, this approach is very common.  You would need to send a unique verification URL (it can be to the same script, with a different query_string) to verify each user.  One way to do this is to DES-encrypt the user_id, send this in the query_string, then your script decrypts the query_string to get the user_id.

Comment: Generate some kind of token or GUID to identify e-mails and include in the verify URL. Display an "already verified" message if the URL is accessed again. Do some kind of cleanup if an e-mail isn't verified for a certain amount of time. Little details like that, but the logic overall is fine.

Comment: @mti2935 -  I was thinking that clicking on "Click me to verify" would simply link to the "Email verified" page and put verified=1 for any user (email) who clicks it (there is no userID since its only a subscription to a newsletter - people enter Name and Email only).

Comment: OK, but let's say 10 people come to your site to sign up for your newsletter.  1 person clicks the 'click me to verify link'.  How do you know which one it was?

Comment: Plus it has to be something "unguessable". Not sequential ID numbers, nor the email address itself, etc.

Comment: @mti2935 [at]ironcito - I see your point, that's where I got stuck before. I have an md5 hash which generates a unique ID but have problem with receiving the email although it's sent. I guess it's back to debugging my scipt. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is Spam Bots, you should use CAPTCHA: http://www.google.com/recaptcha
This will help you against most of them.

**Your solution** is good, if you want to prevent random user using the site, the problems that it solves is that user must put some effort in to it.

Also if you want to save some bandwidth, you can realy go in to email checking: http://www.serviceobjects.com/blog/hot-topics/email-validation-whitepaper/

Hope it helps

Comment: This may work for registering user accounts, but I'm not going to implement a captcha when asking users for e-mail subscription.

Answer (score 1):

you keep captcha protection, it will reduce the bot attacks by many times. And the solution you choose is totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a fine solution.  Then test to make sure the user is verified before sending.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is good email verification solution, but won't solve problem with spambots to signup.

Answer (score 0):

Yours solution is good, but you will send email before validation. It's not always good. If I want to abuse your system I just can submit lots of nonexistent mails to yours registration form. And you will be blocked from main email services. To prevent it you can do email verification before sending email, at least you can check MX records existence or you can integrate with external [email validation api](https://mailcheck.co). Anyway - you should check email address before sending to avoid bounces.